# A good way to get memory usage of a Ruby process in Linux from within itself?

Tags: ruby, linux, memory

I wanted a good way to get memory usage of a Ruby process in Linux from within itself.
For that I defined a Ruby function vmrss() which returns the Resident Set Size of current process:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
def vmrss
    File.readlines('/proc/self/status').select {|l| l =~ /VmRSS/}.first.split[1..-1].join(" ")
end

puts "My current memory consumption: #{vmrss}"
```

Are there any better ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [proc-wait3 library](http://raa.ruby-lang.org/project/proc-wait3/), which adds `Process.getrusage`. It would save you implementing the low-level stuff yourself, but if you only want memory usage, including a library might be overkill, especially given that hasn't been updated in a while.